# Diverging Stacked Bar Charts With Grouping and a Percent Label for each Category/Bar

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2, data-visualization, bar-chart

I have tried visualizing a diverging stacked bar chart with the `HH` package of R, but could not find a way to plot percentage labels. So I moved to the new `likert` package, which is apparently capable of doing that. Running:

```
require(likert)
require(reshape)
data(pisaitems)

items24 <- pisaitems[,substr(names(pisaitems), 1,5) == 'ST24Q']
plot(l24, plot.percents=TRUE)
```

Gives the following plot:
[image: Diverging Stacked Bar Chart with Percentage Labels]

Now I tried plotting the same, grouped by category:

```
l24g <- likert(items24, grouping=pisaitems$CNT)
plot(l24g, plot.percents=TRUE)
```

Giving the following plot:
[image]
Here, however, percentages are NOT shown for each bar/category.
Any idea of how I can somehow plot such a chart with percentage labels for each bar AND group by another factor? If this is not possible, ideas regarding any alternative method of visualizing the data are highly welcome!

Comment: Thanks for the note - it really needs to be on Stack Overflow. The data loads by default with the package likert. Hence: require(likert)... 
data(pisaitems)

Comment: Sorry, I had missed the call to `data()`. You're on SO now, GL.